# Confusion on onto transformations

Tags: linear-algebra

Now transformation of $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^m$ for $n > m$ is an onto function.(Or at least is what I'm understanding).

By definition, for an onto transformed vector **b** there is always a pre-image of **b** for which there exists a *unique* **A<sup>-1</sup>** , let the pre-image be **x**

Again, 
By definition of onto functions(or transformations), two vectors can map to one vector. So, let **a != b** be the two vectors.

But if there's a unique **A<sup>-1</sup>** but there are two vectors that map to the same **b**, how are both of the pre-images found?

Comment: Firstly, a transformation $T: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ with $n > m$ is not "obviously" an onto function. Consider the map $T: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$ with $n > m$ where $\forall \textbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n, T\left( \textbf{x} \right) = \textbf{0}$, where $\textbf{0} \in \mathbb{R}^m$. So, this is not an onto function. In fact it is the trivial linear transformation which maps everything to the zero - vector. Also, ontoness does not guarantee invertibility. So the existence of unique $A^{-1}$ is not guaranteed. But, it does guarantee "at least one pre - image".

Comment: @AniruddhaDeshmukh , but the invertibility matrix theorem states that if A is invertible then there must be at least on solution of Ax=b, which means that the transformation is onto, right?

Comment: In this statement, you are saying that $A^{-1}$ exists and hence the transformation is onto. But, in the question, you have an onto transformation. Is the statement "if and only if"?

Comment: @AniruddhaDeshmukh , so an inverse guarantee onto- ness but an onto- ness does not guarantee invertibility? But if a solution does exist for Ax=b transformation for which it is onto then the solution is unique?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am a bit confused by the question too... However, I try to answer as well as I manage.

> Now transformation of $\mathbb R^n$ to $\mathbb R^m$ for $n > m$ is obviously an onto
>   function.

It does not have to be. For example the linear mapping $\mathbb R^2$ to $\mathbb R^1$ that sends everything to zero is not onto. That transformation is described by matrix $\pmatrix{0 & 0}$.

> By definition, for an onto transformed vector b there is always a pre-image of b for which there exists a unique A-1 , let the pre-image be x

By definition of onto mappings, every element in $\mathbb R^m$ has a preimage, but not necessarily unique. That is not even possible if $n>m$ and the mapping is supposed to be reasonable (for example linear, or continuous).

> Again, By definition of onto functions(or transformations), two vectors can map to one vector. So, let a != b be the two vectors.

That can happen. But just the fact that it *can* happen does not necessarily mean that it will happen. However, it is true in our case of $n>m$, so that part is essentially correct.

> But if there's a unique $A^{-1}$ but there are two vectors that map to the same $b$, how are both of the pre-images found?

There is not an inverse mapping, since the pre-images are not unique. For any $b$ there are not just two pre-images but infinitely many of them. You can find them by solving the equation $Ax = b$ using, say, Gaussian elimination.

Comment: then is the transformation for n < m always an onto?

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/cheatatmathhomework/comments/8fbkpf/the_case_of_onto_transformations/ see the first statement in the answer.

Comment: When n<m, the transformation is never onto.

Comment: The first answer is correct, it is true that if m=0, the transformation have to be onto because it is quite degenerated case,

Comment: he says that a mapping from R^n to 0 is onto, but you say maping from R^n to (0 0 ) is not onto ? What's the difference and how is it not onto?

Comment: Every mapping $\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R^0$ is onto. My mapping is $\mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R^1$, and that is not onto. The difference is that $\mathbb R^0 \neq \mathbb R^1$.

Comment: I can see that 0 != 1 but I meant __Why__ is it not onto?

Comment: For example because the number 1 does not have a preimage.

Comment: And how come zero has one? The number line surely would have it's preimages in R^2 because R^2 is a superset of R^1

Comment: Codomain $\mathbb R^1 = \{\ldots,-2,-1,0,1,2,\ldots,\pi,e,\ldots\}$, and just the element 0 has a preimage. Since all the other elements, that is $-1,1,\pi,\ldots$ does not have preimage, the mapping is not onto. But with codomain $\mathbb R^0={0}$. There is only the element zero that has a preimage, there is no other element in $\mathbb R^0$, so the condition of having preimages is satisfied in that case. I feel like you are missing some basics of functions, try to consult Wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surjective_function, or at least try to formulate a more clear question.